# Error- Multiple declaration for complex::sum

Tags: c++, c++11

while compiling getting error Error- Multiple declaration for complex::sum.

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

class complex
{
    float a,b;
public:
    complex (float m,float n)
    {
        a=m;
        b=n;
    }

    complex sum (complex complex);
    void show (complex);
};
complex complex::sum (complex c1 complex c2)
{
    complex c3;
    c3.a=(c1.a)+(c2.a);
    c3.b=(c1.b)+(c2.b);
    return c3;
}
void complex::show (complex c3)
{
    cout<<c.a<<"+"<<c.b<<"i";
}
int main()
{
    clrscr();
    complex c1,c2,c3 ;
    c1=complex(4.2,9.3);
    c2=complex(12.5,6.5);
    c3=sum(c1,c2);
    cout<<"c1="<<c1.show;
    cout<<"c2="<<c2.show;
    cout<<"c3="<<c3.show;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

what should i do to remove this Multiple declaration for `complex::sum` error. I am using turbo c++ 4.0 version.

Comment: You should really put a comma between your function arguments in `complex::sum` so the compiler knows what you're doing.

Comment: You code is completely irrelevant and has multiple reasons to fail compilation with this error among others. Please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: iostream.h? Really? What book do you read?

Comment: @n.m. I am using turbo c++. also mentioned in question at the end.

Comment: "I am using turbo c++". I have guessed that much. The question is why.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a comma in this declaration

```
complex sum (complex, complex);
                   ^^
```

because the function uses two parameters.

Also the function must be defined appropriately

```
complex complex::sum (complex c1, complex c2)
                               ^^^
{
    complex c3( c1.a + c2.a, c1.b + c2.b );
    return c3;
}
```

It would be more correctly to write

```
/* const */ complex complex::sum ( const complex &c1, const complex &c2 ) const
{
    complex c3( c1.a + c2.a, c1.b + c2.b );
    return c3;
}
```

Take into account that the class does not have the default constructor.

The function show should be declared either as static or without parameter as for example

```
void show() /*const*/;
```

And the function should be called like

```
cout<<"c1="<<c1.show();
                    ^^^
cout<<"c2="<<c2.show();
                    ^^^
```

Comment: @VladfromMoscow just compiled again with comma. and error increased from 1 to 9 with 3 warnings

Comment: @manish See my updated post. Your program has other mistakes.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow modified program as you said. now compiler showing lots of error including complex ::sum n complex::show not member of complex

Comment: @manish The function declaration must coincide with the function definitions. If the const qualifier is present either in declaration or a definition then it must present in the both.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow after placing comma in complex complex::sum ( const complex &c1, const complex &c2 ) const error count increases. when i remove that comma it shows single error "multiple declaration" new in c++ trying this code since 3 hrs. no luck.

Comment: @manish As I said already you check that declarations are equivalent to definitions.

Answer (score 0):

finally got output. here is working code

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

class complex
{
    float a,b;

public:
    complex (float m,float n)
    {
    a=m;
    b=n;
    }

    complex sum (complex, complex);
    void show (complex);
};
complex complex::sum ( complex c1,complex c2)
{

    complex c3(c1.a+c2.a, c1.b+c2.b);

    return c3;
}
void complex::show (complex c3)
{
    cout<<c3.a<<"+"<<c3.b<<"i";
}

int main()
{  clrscr();
   float p,q,r,s;
   cin>>p>>q>>r>>s;
   complex c3(c3.sum(complex(p,q),complex(r,s)));

    cout<<"c3=";
    c3.show(c3);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```